# Syntax for Python tuples

Tags: python, tuples

If a function is written like this

```
 def validate(input):
        for a, b in input:
        ......
```

What is the syntactic form of `input`? I've tried a `tuple` but the function says there are "too many values to unpack".

Comment: `validate([(a1, b1), (a2, b2), …])` – or another *sequence* of tuples. I'm guessing you just passed one tuple, or might really want to do `a, b = input` instead of `for a, b in input`. If you're getting an error message, it'd be helpful to provide the code that **causes** it.

Answer (score 6):

In this case:

1. `input` is an [iterable type](http://docs.python.org/2.7/glossary.html#term-iterable) (a list, tuple, etc.)
2. Its items are also iterable types.  However, each item has exactly 2 items of its own.

---

I think the best way to explain this is with a demonstration:

```
>>> def validate(input):
...     for a,b in input:
...         print a,b
...
>>> data = [(0,1), (2,3), (4,5)]
>>> validate(data)
0 1
2 3
4 5
>>>
```

In the above code, notice how `data` is an iterable type (a list) and each of its items are iterable types (tuples in this case) that contain exactly 2 items.

Answer (score 3):

`for a,b in input` expects `input` to be an [iterable](http://docs.python.org/2.7/glossary.html#term-iterable) in which each element is a sub-iterable with exactly two items, e.g., `((1,2), ("foo", "bar"), ([], None))` but not `(1, 2)` or `((0,1), (2,3,4))`.